# What is going on with Google App Engine today?

Tags: google-app-engine

The [GAE status page](https://code.google.com/status/appengine) responds **very** slowly and sometimes just returns 500 errors. There is no information on the issues yet and https://appengine.google.com/ is only returning 500s, too.

Comment: https://twitter.com/search?q=%23gae Google App Engine is down.. so there is nothing we can do.. until they resolve it

Comment: while the status page and the dashboard have started working again for me, appcf.sh rollbacks fail with 400 Bad Request errors. i cannot deploy to my app or rollback deploys that timed out.

Comment: now I am seeing 502 Bad Gateway errors when I am trying to deploy a new version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the [Official Support Thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-downtime-notify/SMd2pDJsCPo/discussion)

Answer (score 4):

Please follow this thread for updates:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine-downtime-notify/SMd2pDJsCPo

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday (in the python environment) I experienced an issue with the GAE "automatic scaling" creating tens of dynamic instances. I usually run 1-4 instances, suddenly, it when to 100 instances, with no apparent spike of traffic.

Could have been a fluke, but my guess is that the problem I experienced just propagated onto a larger scale, bringing down the whole thing. Until Google makes a statement, we won't have a clear idea.